# Binding is called after event handler in silverlight CheckBox

Tags: binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a checkbox in silverlight and I have binded the checkbox IsChecked property with one string property which stores the value like 'True' and 'False'. I have used a converter in the binding to convert the string value to bool. I also have the event handler for checkbox 'checked' and 'unchecked' event.

When I checked or unchecked the checkbox , binding update as well as the handler for the checkbox ''checked' and 'unchecked' event is called but hanlder is called first and then binding updates. But I require checkbox to update the binding first (for IsChecked property) and then the event hanlder to get called. How can I achieve this.

// property with which I am binding IsChecked property is 'PropertyPath'

```
 // binding code

 CheckBox checkBoxControl = new CheckBox();    
 Binding binding = new Binding();
 binding.FallbackValue = false;
 binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
 binding.Source = this;
 binding.Converter = new BoolStringToBoolConverter();
 binding.Path = new PropertyPath("PropertyPath");     
 checkBoxControl.SetBinding(GenericCheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);

  checkBoxControl.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(checkBox_CheckedProperty_Changed);

handler


       void checkBox_CheckedProperty_Changed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chkBox = sender as CheckBox;    
            // Here the value of 'PropertyPath' is not updated as binding is not   updated yet
        }
```

below is the converter I am using in binding

```
public class BoolStringToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value.ToString().ToUpper().Trim().Equals("TRUE"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value.GetType().Equals(typeof(bool)) && (bool)value)
            {
                return "True";
            }
            else
            {
                return "False" ;
            }
        }
    }
```

On clicking the checkbox the event handler is getting called first and then 'ConvertBack' method of converter gets called and hence in the event handler I dont get the updated value of property 'PropertyPath'.

How can I make sure to call the binding updates before calling the checkbox event handler.